# Simplifying $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

How do I simplify $\sqrt{(4+2\sqrt{3})}+\sqrt{(4-2\sqrt{3})}$?

I've tried to make it $x$ and square both sides but I got something extremely complicated and it didn't look right.

I got $2\sqrt{3}$ on wolframalpha, but I'm not sure how is it possible?

Help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\ \ \ \sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}
\\
\\
&=\sqrt{(\sqrt{3}+1)^2}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2}\
\\
\\
&=\sqrt{3}+1+\sqrt{3}-1
\\
\\
&=\boxed{2\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 24):

You have the right idea in squaring and then taking the square root.

Note that $k = (\sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{3}} + \sqrt{4 - 2\sqrt{3}})^{2} = 4 + 2\sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{(4+2\sqrt{3})(4-2\sqrt{3})} + 4 - 2\sqrt{3}$

But this is just:

$k = 8 + 2\sqrt{16 - 12} = 12$

So

$\sqrt{k} = 2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Good solution, certainly much better than mine.

Comment: I wouldn't say that @AndréNicolas, just less observant than yours ;)

Comment: +1 Much better explanation than the "rabbit out of a hat" accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

Since $(4+2\sqrt3)(4-2\sqrt3)=16-12=4$, try squaring:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}+\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}\right)^2
&=(4+2\sqrt3)+(4-2\sqrt3)+2\sqrt{(4+2\sqrt3)(4-2\sqrt3)}\\
&=8+2\sqrt{16-12}\\[6pt]
&=12
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt3}+\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}=2\sqrt3$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Find the square of $1+\sqrt{3}$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 6):

Write as $\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}} = a+b\sqrt{3}$. Now square both sides, equate real and radical part. This gives two equations in $a$ and $b$. Now eliminate $a$, solve for $b$. Goes perfect. Same for the other term.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate $a+b$ where $a^2=4+2\sqrt3$ and $b^2=4-2\sqrt3$.

You could notice that $a^2$ and $b^2$ are [roots of the quadratic equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-8x%2B4)
$$x^2-8x+4=0.$$
(To find this equation you just need to find appropriate coefficients in [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).)

Now from [Viete's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) you get
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2&=8\\
a^2b^2&=4
\end{align*}
which (together with the fact that $a,b>0$) leaves you with $ab=2$ and $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab=8+2\cdot3=12.$$
You get that $$a+b=\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the following formula:

$$\sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+c}{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a-c}{2}}$$

where

$c=\sqrt{a^2-b}$